# Usage of SP_OACreate, SP_OAMethod etc.. is a security risk?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am told that usage of SP_OACreate , SP_OAMethod in SQL Server 2000 is of a security risk.

I am using Strong Name in the  assembly and is stored in GAC  on the SQL Server Machine.

What are the security implications/compromise ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These extended stored procedures allow one to instantiate an OLE ("ActiveX") object from inside SQL Server. A typical use case creating an MSXML object and having it send some database data as an HTTP POST.

In my mind, there are two issues with the sp_OACreate etc procedures:

- Only principals in the sysadmin role can execute these by default. Granting and testing these permissions is a pain. (You have to add the user to the Master database and grant them permissions in that database.)
- The permission granted is very broad. You can't just say "ok user, you have the right to create this kind of object and do xyz with it." Instead you say "ok user, you have the right to create any OLE object you want and do anything you want." That is a pretty broad canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your attempting but for SQL 2000 you should read [Using extended stored procedures or SP_OA stored procedures to load CLR in SQL Server is not supported](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;322884).

The risk is that you must grant `EXECUTE` permission on `SP_OACreate` to the user.
This means that if they subsequently found a way to execute arbitrary SQL they could create instances of any library available on the server.
Another issue is that `SP_OACreate` loads the library in-process, so if it bombs, so does your server.

Comment: I am parsing sql string stored as ntext within given table and returning result as row set   (Client expect the result in a data table).
PS:
Execute permissions has to be granted for any user who requires to execute them..
Only difference I can see is that we have to set  Execute permission to SP_OACreate etc explicitly..